# Where is MediaStore.Images.Media stored on Android devices

Tags: android

I was looking at using:

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()`

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

but after i've successfully saved an image from bitmap, i can't find it anywhere on my external SD card. how do i get access to this using my ADB Shell tool?

all that the `filePath` says is: `content://media/external/images/media/22375`